# Unable to use gateway once in OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to get an OpenVPN server working to give clients access to a network that is 10.202.0.0/16. I'd like the OpenVPN clients range to be 10.202.46.1-255. I have configured the server, and can connect to it fine. I'm using it to replace the default gateway of the client. However, for some reason the OpenVPN server is giving my client the address 10.202.46.6 and says my default gateway is 10.202.46.5. I can ping 10.202.46.1, but I can not ping anything else within the network. My server.conf file can be read at http://pastebin.com/jM3G5yhV. Anyone have any ideas why I can't ping anything else in the network? The gateway of the 10.202.0.0/16 network is 10.202.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the gateway for the `10.202.0.0/16` network is `10.202.1.1`.  Do you mean that `10.202.1.1` actually has a subnet mask of `255.255.0.0`?  If so, then your setup is extremely broken.

The network you have setup for your VPN server `server 10.202.46.0 255.255.255.0` is within the `10.202.0.0/16` subnet.  This means you are going to have a serious routing problem.

Nothing in `10.202.0.0/16` will know how to reach hosts in the `10.202.46.0/24` network.  Hosts in `10.202.0.0/16` will be arping directly for the hosts instead of trying to contact the VPN server as a gateway.

OpenVPN setups should be treated like a router.  The address space used for the VPN clients should be a completely separate subnet from the network that you are routing.  You need to set up routes properly on all network devices so that the traffic for the VPN subnet is correctly directed to the VPN server.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the netmask of the gateway is 255.255.0.0. I think I'm not understanding OpenVPN correctly. I'm coming from using PPTP, and from that, I just need to give the clients IPs within the existing subnet, and they just become clients on that network. For OpenVPN, does it have to be a completely new network, that talks to the existing network through the firewall?

Comment: PPTP tunnels at layer 2.  The prefered setup of OpenVPN (routed mode) tunnels at layer 3.  This means that you need an additional subnet for OpenVPN, and you need to setup routing properly to support it.  You can setup OpenVPN in bridged mode which will make it more like PPTP, but it is less efficient, bridged mode really only should be used if you are transporting a protocol other than IPv4/IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct since openvpn gives you a small subnet to use. Try just enabling ip forwarding on your server and see if that helps

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Iptables will also push our routes for the networks you setup so it will send traffic over the tunnel.

Comment: That is important, but I suspect there is a much bigger routing problem given the subnets that were mentioned in the question and config.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure push route section on openvpn server config? AFAIR you must push routes from server so that clients could know that they must send packets to openvpn network through openvpn network interface.